# Error when Styling a combo box with multiple triggers

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, triggers

I have a combo box to which I am trying to add some styles hence inside my Combobox. Style I am trying to set triggers for two properties but it seems like it doesn't allow me to set both properties at once. The code I am having trouble is below

The error displayed says Property elements cannot be in the middle of an element's content. They must be before or after the content

```
<ComboBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="..." />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="..." />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>

        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsExecuting}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Style>
```

Am I writing syntactically wrong XAML here? would appreciate some help here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This compiles for me:

```
<ComboBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
            </Trigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsExecuting}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Style>
```

All I did was made sure there is only one `Style.Triggers`

Comment: is there anything that says there can be only one Style.Trigger?
I wasn't aware of a such a thiing actually

Comment: I was not aware of such thing either, I don't think there is a property called `Style.Trigger` but there is `Style.Triggers` and while looking through your code the property had an "s" at the end of it so that indicates there can be multiple Triggers inside, and if I can put multiple Triggers in side `Style.Triggers` I would not want another `Style.Triggers`  atleast not in the same style.

Comment: I see what you mean there ...So I think where there are many properties involved and we ant to add trigger its better to write all our triggers inside a single set of Style.Triggers tag